# How to change the list of kdims of a holoviews Dataset

Tags: holoviews

I have a tabular data set and it has multiple columns that might be the key dimension for some plots.

```
ds = hv.Dataset(data_df, kdims=['time', 'forecasttime', 'group'], vdims=['speed'])
```

I could initial use a curve plot:

```
ds.to(hv.Curve, kdims=['time'], vdims=['speed'])
```

This would provide timeseries curves with a selector widget on 'forecasttime', 'group'.

What I would like to achieve is to plot a curve that ignores the key dimenion 'forecasttime', 'group'. While I could certain achieve the samething by defining my Dataset object in a different way like the following:

```
ds = hv.Dataset(data_df, kdims=['time'], vdims=['speed'])
ds.to(hv.Curve, kdims=['time'], vdims=['speed'])
```

I was hoping that I could remove a key dimension from the kdims of ds **after** it is defined. What could I do?

I am new to holoviews. Perhaps I am not using holoviews's Dataset object the correct way. I would also appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily ignore the additional dimensions by declaring the `groupby` keyword to be empty in the call to `.to`, e.g.

```
ds.to(hv.Curve, kdims=['time'], vdims=['speed'], groupby=[])
```

That said in the case of a Curve it is a bit weird to just ignore a dimension and you may end up with the curve zig-zagging across the plot. Since I don't know the structure of your data this may well be a valid thing to do though. If you instead want to overlay each Curve something like this might be what you want:

```
ds.to(hv.Curve, kdims=['time'], vdims=['speed'], groupby=['group']).overlay()
```

or written more simply:

```
ds.to(hv.Curve, 'time', 'speed', 'group').overlay()
```

Comment: Where can I find more documentation about the groupby keyword? In general, I am bit confused about the Dataset concept and how they are related to Curve, etc. Should I think about Dataset as the data and Curve/Scatter etc as different way of visualizing the data? Thanks a lot for the response and thanks a lot for making holoviews.